# Solve diffusion equation with Neumann boundary conditions and zero initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The problem I have to solve is the following:

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} -c \frac{\partial ^2p}{\partial x^2}=0 \quad \quad (x,t) \in (0,L)\times[0,\infty)$

with

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x=0,t) =Q \quad \quad t>0$

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x=L,t) =0  \quad \quad t>0$

$p(x, t=0)=0  \quad \quad x \in (0,L)$

where Q is a constant.

So, there are two different Neumann boundary conditions, and a zero initial condition.

I tried to solve by separation of variables but I'm stuck at this stage, as I don't know how to impose the boundary conditions and the initial condition.  I suspect I should use Fourier series but I don't really understand how to do it when the initial condition is 0.

Could someone help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: Something along those lines? http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s12/m3357/lectures/lecture_2_28_short.pdf

Comment: I looked into it, but unfortunately it didn't really help me with my initial and boundary conditions, as they are a bit specific in my case.